# Ensuring multiple subscriptions have completed before condition is checked

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am using ngrx and I want to ensure that both subscriptions in my ngOnInit() are completed before I check conditions and invoke methods based on the conditions.

My code looks like below:

```
ngOnInit(){

       this.status$ = this.store.pipe(
         takeWhile(()=> this.isAlive),
         select(Selectors.getStatus)
       );

      this.process$ = this.store.pipe(
         takeWhile(()=> this.isAlive),
         select(Selectors.getProcess)
       );

       this.status$.subscribe(status => {
          this.staus = staus;

          this.status$.subscribe(process=> {
          this.process= process;

          if(!this.process.someBooleanProperty && this.status.success){
              callMethodA();
          }else if(!this.process.someBooleanProperty && this.status.error){
              callMethodB();
          }
       });
});
```

I want to ensure that before I test my condition the status$ has completed so I put process$ subscription inside status$ subscription.

I was looking for ways to improve this and if there are some operators which ensures that both subscription are completed before the condition is evaluated. I came across forkJoin operator in RxJs
and refactored the code using it as below:

```
ngOnInit(){

   forkJoin(
       this.status$.pipe(takeWhile(()=> this.isAlive)).pipe(tap(status => this.status = status)),
       this.process$.pipe(takeWhile(()=> this.isAlive)).pipe(tap(process=> this.process= process))
   ).susbscribe(() => {
       if(!this.process.someBooleanProperty && this.status.success){
          callMethodA();
      }else if(!this.process.someBooleanProperty && this.status.error){
          callMethodB();
      }
   }); 
}
```

The above code using forkJoin doesn't work and debugger doesn't even reaches the line of codde having condition. As I am a backend developer learning fron-end, I am unable to understand the reason. Please can someone help me identify the  mistake in my approach. Also, is approach one bad ?

Comment: i guess that not all observables completed. They might emitted something, but didn't complete yet. To verify it use something like `this.status$.subscribe(()=> console.log('Emitted'), () => console.log('Error'), () => console.log('Completed'))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to keep track of the live status of status$ and process$, from the logic you present, because these two stream doesn't seem like a one off stream to me. you can use `combineLatest` instead

```
  combineLatest(
       this.status$,
       this.process$
   ).pipe(
       tap(([status,process)=>{... do you condition check and method call here and set isAlive appropriately })
       takeWhile(()=> this.isAlive)).subscribe()
```